# What is the standard way of showing the user that a context menu is available in a user interface?

Tags: icons, contextual-menu

In the picture below, the same icon is used for two different actions. The ones to the right expand and collapses the section, whereas the ones to the left open a classic context menu.

I find this confusing and it might add cognitive load. I wonder what would be the appropriate way of displaying the context menu next to the server time and hour in this example.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**When it comes to popping up a contextual menu, the [overflow icon](https://thenounproject.com/term/action-overflow/) is now widely used for that purpose**. If the majority of websites your users visit already use this convention, It makes sense to leverage on this learned mental model already.

So to answer your question: use an overflow icon *(horizontal or vertical is fine)*. You may even add a border to it on hover.

[image]